# How to define dynamic route path using regex in Nuxt's serverMiddleware?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, node-request, path-to-regexp

I'm trying to define a regex based dynamic path in Nuxt's serverMiddleware, but I'm not able to figure out how to achieve it because in the doc also there is no any mention about dynamic route.

I want to achieve something like this,

```
// ./nuxt.config.js
export default {
    modules: [
      ..
    ],
    serverMiddleware: [
        {
            path: '/sitemap/:filename(.*xml.gz)',
            handler: '~/api/serveSitemap.js'
        }
    ]  
}
```

And then get :filename param inside the handler..

```
//./api/serveSitemap.js
export default function(req, res) {
    filename = req.params.filename // is 'req.params' available in nodejs?
    // some code
    res.end()
}
```

Just to inform, I'm using Nuxtjs in SSR mode with Nodejs as a rendering server, and not using Expressjs.
And this is the link which I'm referring for using Nuxt serverMiddleware:
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/#custom-server-middleware

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @ßiansor Sorry guys, I didn't find any solution for this problem yet, nor do I know the reason why it doesn't work. Just because of this shortcoming I had to change the approach towards my problem. Hope someone from Nuxt community helps to find the solution or at least some work around for this.